# Grok Pattern for WSO2 Audit Log file

Tags: wso2, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, audit-logging

This is a example from WSO2 Audit log file

```
[2016-11-22 00:20:30,657]  INFO -  Initiator : wso2.system.user | Action : 
Change Password by User | Target : admin | Data : {  } | Result : Success
```

I am trying to write a Grok pattern using frok debugger, but all I am getting is No Matches.

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}-%{SPACE}%
{GREEDYDATA:log_message}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern is missing a space between `%{LOGLEVEL:level}` and the following dash (`-`).
It would look like this : `...%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}...` or `...%{LOGLEVEL:level} -%{SPACE}...` (you don't have to use `%{SPACE}` if you are sure the number of spaces will always be the same).

Comment: Thanks mate. It helped!

Comment: @sriramsm04 you're welcome. A few resources to help you next time: [grok filter tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result), [grok filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and [base grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).